# Componente FullCalendar PrimeNg

Tags: angular

Bom dia!

Eu estou tentando inserir o componente FullCalendar do PrimeNg em um projeto que estou fazendo. Eu segui a documentação, de acordo com o site do PrimeNg, porém o calendário não fica correto (conforme imagem). Alguém que já tenha trabalhado com esse componente, saberia dizer se precisa de mais alguma coisa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo está o código do TypeScript, seguindo a como está na documentação.

```
this.events = [
  {
    'title': 'All Day Event',
    'start': '2019-04-01'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Long Event',
    'start': '2019-04-07',
    'end': '2019-04-10'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Repeating Event',
    'start': '2019-04-09T16:00:00'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Repeating Event',
    'start': '2019-04-16T16:00:00'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Conference',
    'start': '2019-04-11',
    'end': '2019-04-13'
  }
];

this.options = {
  defaultDate: '2019-04-01',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  }
};
```

Abaixo o código HTML

```
   <p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
```

Comment: Você já instalou o tema?

Comment: Sim, fiz as instalações que são descritas na documentação.